# npm init - What on Earth are the questions asking?

Tags: npm

I'm struggling to learn all the strange JavaScript front-end tools. I'm a Microsoft guy so I'm used to being very highly-productive at the expense of knowing cool JavaScript tools or rocking a hipster beard.

I think I need to initialize NPM in my project with `npm init` but its asking questions with single words and I haven't the faintest clue what to respond, the docs don't even mention the questions.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init

So what do I put for `name:` and `version:` and any others that might be asked next?

Thanks!!

Comment: Not an actual answer, but a good word of advice would be to read more about [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json).

Comment: Outside the desktop, Microsoft is a minor player, and there aren't many buttons to do things for you. Knowing the environment, tools and documentation are important.

Comment: You have CLI commands to do things for you. Difference is that GUI wizards usually have richer integral documentation. I don't see why a CLI tool can't use more words and clearer explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`npm init` is for creating a new package.json with npm.

`npm install` is for installing all dependencies.

The question is, why do you think you need to `npm init` - when you do not know which name your project has.

If you want to create a new project, add the name of the project and the version - for example `0.0.1`. Use semantic versioning for this, see http://semver.org/ .

The name is the name of your project. The version is the version of your project and if its a private app, then you can just put 1.0.0 in and leave it; its more for libraries you may be intending to add to a shared package repository.

Comment: It's for making a package.json to get started with npm, and I need that for the build server to do an npm install later, but what's the name for? Name of the file or what? What's the version the version of npm, node, my app? It's just not clear. That's my problem with these tools, they're rushed.

Comment: You need a `project.json` for all informations regarding your project. If you just need to install a packge, you can just type `npm install package-name`. If you want to create a `package.json` then you can enter the name of your current working directory. The Version is the version of your project. All of this is described in the docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Comment: Thanks for your help, maybe I've got it completely wrong. What's the file that lists the packages I'm using so that they can be installed automatically by a build server, other team members??

Comment: If you use a build server, and others depends on this project you **need** a version and a project-name. The `package.json` is then the file you search for. Insert the `name` and the `version` of **your** project, not npm or node.

Comment: Okay, thanks, the version is just the version of my app and since its private and not a public package for other npm users, I can just stick 1.0.0 in there and forget about it?

Comment: If it is an `app` and not a library (and it is not a dependency for others projects then) it is totally fine to stick with the `1.0.0` version - yes.

Comment: You can also set `private: yes` in you `package.json` to prevent publishing to npmjs.org